# How to show Android contacts list

Tags: android

when I click show button then It is error.
But I have given permission contacts.

What's problem I can not understand.

Error Log :

```
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 2
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:424)
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
07-02 10:29:06.262: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at com.example.contentprovidernew_ahsanul.MainActivity.displayContracts(MainActivity.java:74)
```

My [Full code](http://codepad.org/kfNAFgSa)

Comment: use `cursor.moveToFirst()` before do while in `displayContracts` (line 73 ), and post your code here instead of post a link to your code

Comment: by using intent also can view contact list.. try tht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
cursor.moveToFirst(); // add this : moves to first 
            do{
                String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                 int hasphoneNumber=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                 if(hasphoneNumber>0){
                     Cursor phCursor=cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID+"=?", new String[]{id}, null);
                     if(phCursor!=null && phCursor.getCount()>0){
                        phCursor.moveToFirst();
                         do{
                             String phoneNumber=phCursor.getString(phCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber+" "+ name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }while(phCursor.moveToNext());// change here : use moveToNext()
                     }
                     phCursor.close();
                 }

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: you need change `while(phCursor.moveToFirst())` to `while(phCursor.moveToNext())` too as TeRRo said

Comment: he is getting Error At line :74 and i have putted my code before :74 number line

Comment: yes, your code fixed first problem of OP, but this code has a unlimited loop on getting number as I said, because `phCursor.moveToFirst()` is always true

Answer (score 0):

On line 86 I think that is the problem.

Change:

```
                    phCursor.moveToFirst();
                     do{
                         String phoneNumber=phCursor.getString(phCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber+" "+ name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                     }while(phCursor.moveToFirst());
```

to:

```
                    phCursor.moveToFirst();
                     do{
                         String phoneNumber=phCursor.getString(phCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), phoneNumber+" "+ name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }while(phCursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: what is different this??

Comment: This while(phCursor.moveToNext());